# Use one DataContext.ExecuteCommand to execute query for multiple tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework, datacontext, sql-server-ce-4

I need to delete all data from my tables in database. So I use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand`.

```
db.ExecuteCommand("DELETE From Products");
```

This method causes a new request to the database for each table. I want to clear data from my tables in one query. But all my attempts so far were unsuccessful.

Is it possible to use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` to delete data from multiple tables (multiple SQL queries)?

---

```
        try
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                context.DeleteAll();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(exception);
        }

private static void DeleteAll(this DataContext context)
        {
            var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

            ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [RegionProducts]; DELETE FROM [ProductTypes]; DELETE FROM [Measurements]; DELETE FROM [Sizes]; " +
                                    "DELETE FROM [Regions]; DELETE FROM [Types]; DELETE FROM [Categories]; DELETE FROM [Images] where Product_Id is not null; DELETE FROM [Products]; " +
                                    "DELETE FROM [Brands]; DELETE FROM [Images];");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will heavily depend on the **actual database system** you're using - but in the case of e.g. SQL Server, you should be able to have multiple `DELETE` statements - separated by a semicolon - like this:

```
string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dbo.Products; DELETE FROM dbo.OtherTable; DELETE FROM dbo.YetAnotherTable;";

db.ExecuteCommand(deleteQuery);
```

Of course, you need to pay attention to any possible FK relationships that might cause one delete to fail, if other tables still reference its data - but it should be possible to do this in a single `db.ExecuteCommand` call

**Update:** unfortunately, in SQL Server **Compact Edition** v4 that you're using, you cannot have multiple SQL statements in a single command - it is just not supported. This approach works **just fine** in the *real* SQL Server - but it will **not** work in SQL Server **CE** ...

Comment: about FK - I've found correct way of deleting data from tables when I make `ExecuteCommand` for separate server. I hope it will work in query as in your example?

Comment: Don't know why, but I get error : `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 31,Token in error = DELETE ]`

Comment: Would be better to use `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` if `context is DataContext` ?

Comment: What **version** and **edition** of SQL Server are you using? Is this SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition) by any chance??

Comment: **AHHHH!!!!** That explains it (and you didn't ever mention that before - please **do tell us** what system you're using - always - and just "SQL" isn't a product - it's a language - so that doesn't usually help....). Unfortunately, SQL Server **COMPACT** doesn't allow multiple SQL statements in a single command - you cannot delete from all tables in a single command in SQL Server CE (the *real* SQL Server can do this, no problem)